# Unity android plugin C# code to start activity

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I am developing unity android plugin and was wondering if there is a way to start an android Activity class from c# code.

That is something that is equivalent to android code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context,some_activity.class);
```

Comment: Did you try using package name instead?

Answer (score 3):

here is how I call my plugin for an AR application build with Unity for Android:
firstly define your plugin:

```
private AndroidJavaClass plugin;
```

later on Start()

```
plugin = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");
```

Later when you want to call your plugin:

```
ΑndroidJavaClass jc = new AndroidJavaClass("com.package.name.ActivityName");
AndroidJavaObject jo = plugin.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");
string msg= "a msg to send to android activity";
jo.Call("buttonClicked", msg);
```

`buttonClicked` is the method in Java side. After getting to that method you can call any activity using Intents

You should create a jar of your plugin and add it inside the plugin folder of your Unity project.

For more details you can check [here](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PluginsForAndroid.html)